# How to validate all form fields except for one?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the form below, I need to validate that **First Name**, **Last Name** and **Gender** have been completed. **Birth** needs to be excluded from the validation. I've set up the validation for all the elements, but I'm not sure how to exclude just one field.

**How do I validate all but one field before removing the `disabled` attribute?**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel blank-panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form action="" name="addNewPersonForm" id="addNewPersonForm">
            <div class="form-group required">
              <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
                <label for="fname" class="is-required">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" onkeyup="validateForm()">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
                <label for="lname" class="is-required">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" onkeyup="validateForm()">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="gender" class="is-required">Gender</label>
                <select class="form-control" onkeyup="validateForm()">
                  <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
                  <option value="1">Female</option>
                  <option value="2">Male</option>
                  <option value="3">Unspecified</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="birthDate" class="control-label">Birth</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="birthDateDiv">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" id="birthDate" name="birthDate">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="dummy" class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" id="addPerson" value="Add
                            Person" disabled="disabled">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure why you set a `keyup` event for a select, second please provide your validation method.

Comment: It's client-side validation? It's in the JS. If all the fields are complete (or have more than 0 characters), then the `disabled` attribute is removed.

Comment: If you have a suggestion to help make this better, I look forward to your response.

Comment: Or just use html5 validation with the required attribute on the ones that are required and the browser will handle the submit button.

Comment: Nope. I need to leave the button disabled until the form fields are complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function validateForm(){
    const fields = document.querySelectorAll(".is-required + input,.is-required + select");
    console.log("Fields to validate:", fields)
}
</script>
```